# Remove stopwords of a sentence using Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, nlp, data.table, rcpp

I would like to replace the words of a sentence based on the stopwords of another vector using `Rcpp`. An example in `R` follows:

```
library(stringr)
library(tm)

x <- "I love eating burgers every day and night"
idVector <- str_split(x,pattern = " ")[[1]]
idVector <- idVector[!idVector %in% stopwords(kind = "en")]
idVector <- paste0(idVector, collapse = " ")
print(idVector)
```

I would be interested to create a `Rcpp` function and perform a group by over the rows of a `data.table` in order to clean a huge amount of sentences. Using the current approach it takes significant amount of time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, you could speed this up by avoiding using regex in the split operation, e.g. `idVector <- strsplit(x, " ", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]` (no need in using tidlyverse everywhere). You could also store the stopwords in a vector in order to avoid calling that function (if you run it many times), such `stpwrds <- stopwords(kind = "en")` and then use that vector instead. Second of all, everything here is vectgorized, and you are operating over vectors so I doubt `data.table` or Rcpp will show any performance boost. Finally, printing to console can consume some time.

Comment: You could perhaps to the whole think in one step using `stringi` but it uses regex so I doubt it will be faster. Something like `stringi:::stri_replace_all_regex(x, paste0("\\b", stopwords(kind = "en"), "\\b"), "", vectorize_all = FALSE)`